# Rotating refresh button

Tags: android

I have a refresh button defined in a layout file as follow:

```
<ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/btn_refresh_assets"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:onClick="onClick"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh" />
```

When his button clicked, an `AsyncTask` is called to load data from a webservice. Now I want to rotate the refresh icon until the load is complete!!!
there is some guidlines for doing this in actionbar but my button is placed in the middle of a page and not in actionbar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is code

```
Animation animation = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.5f);
        animation.setRepeatCount(-1);
        animation.setDuration(2000);
```

create animation

Before starting service attach animation to imageview as below

```
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btn_refresh_assets)).setAnimation(animation);
```

and when service ends

```
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btn_refresh_assets)).clearAnimation();
```

Comment: in this way my imageButton is rotating but when i set its background to null  (android:background="@null") then the animation is not playing!!! have you any suggestion???!!!